# jQuery Form .live submit event in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I've got some jQuery 1.4.4 code

```
$('.AJAXForm').live('submit', function (e) { .... });
```

that's working fine in IE but not in Firefox.  I'm loading the forms into divs on `$(document).ready(...)` with

```
$('#DivPlaceHolderName').load('URLName .AJAXPageSection');
```

so that it loads just the section of the target page containing the form object (so that the target form pages also function standalone, in case scripting isn't enabled) but the .live function isn't binding to the form objects when it runs in Firefox.  I've tried manually putting an equivalent form on the page itself and it runs the code fine, but the live aspect doesn't seem to work when the forms are subsequently loaded.  This works fine with a link (a separate, but similar set of code) and also in Opera, so I'm guessing it's a Firefox issue with the 'submit' event?  If so, is there a workaround for FF?

Thx

MH

Comment: Why not just use a live 'click' function?

Comment: Because it's a form submit event and that doesn't necessarily involve a click (esp, from an atomic POV) if there's other scripts assigned to a form that this is being applied to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has been significantly improved since 1.4.4. I'd try [The latest version of jQuery (1.6.2 as of this post)](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js) to see if the issue has been fixed in the source.

Comment: Is this a known issue that's been fixed in 1.5/6?

Comment: You can read the release notes for each of the versions from 1.4.4 to 1.6.2 to see if they fixed it, or try using the latest version and see if your bug goes away: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release